# not able to export certain variables and get 'not a valid identifier'

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I am on ubuntu 16.x and getting this below error. how to get around?

```
export machineType-argo="c1.medium"
-bash: export: `machineType-argo=c1.medium': not a valid identifier
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash variable names can contain latin letters, digits and underscores (`_`). Hyphens (`-`) are not allowed, that's why you get this error.

[Prooflink](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Definitions):

> name A word consisting solely of letters, numbers, and underscores,
>   and beginning with a letter or underscore. Names are used as shell
>   variable and function names. Also referred to as an identifier.

Comment: awesome!. so hyphen '-' in variable name but in value its allowed.